# Join two pyspark dataframes on calculated value in condition

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. I need to find for the given keys (k1) the minimum dates where the minimal date cannot be 01-01-2020 or above and where found replace the dates (start and end) from df2.  The example;

```
data = [('A','a','03-05-2010','02-02-2019'),
   ('B','a','02-12-2010','01-02-2011'),
   ('B','b','02-12-2010','01-02-2011'),
   ('B','c','02-12-2010','01-02-2011'),
   ('B','d','03-01-2013','01-03-2015'),
   ('B','e','04-01-2014','01-01-2020'),
   ('C','a','01-01-2020','01-01-2020')
 ]

schema = StructType([ \
   StructField("k1",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("k2",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("start",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("end",StringType(),True), \
 ])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df1.show()

+---+---+----------+----------+
| k1| k2|     start|       end|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  A|  a|03-05-2010|02-02-2019|
|  B|  a|02-12-2010|01-02-2011|
|  B|  b|02-12-2010|01-02-2011|
|  B|  c|02-12-2010|01-02-2011|
|  B|  d|03-01-2013|01-03-2015|
|  B|  e|04-01-2014|01-01-2020|
|  C|  a|01-01-2020|01-01-2020|
+---+---+----------+----------+

#df2

+---+---+----------+----------+
| k1| k2|     start|       end|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  A|  a|03-05-2010|02-02-2019|
|  B|  a|01-01-2008|01-02-2008|
|  B|  b|01-11-2009|01-12-2009|
|  B|  c|02-01-2010|01-02-2010|
|  B|  e|04-01-2014|01-01-2020|
|  D|  a|01-01-2000|01-01-2001|
+---+---+----------+----------+
```

and the result should look like this:

```
+---+---+----------+----------+
| k1| k2|     start|       end|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  A|  a|03-05-2010|02-02-2019| #no change as it matches by key
|  B|  a|01-01-2008|01-02-2008| #replaced with df2's start and end because the date in df1 for k1 was the minimal value 01-02-2011 
|  B|  b|01-11-2009|01-12-2009| #replaced with df2's start and end because the date in df1 for k1 was the minimal value 01-02-2011
|  B|  c|02-01-2010|01-02-2010| #replaced with df2's start and end because the date in df1 for k1 was the minimal value 01-02-2011
|  B|  d|03-01-2013|01-03-2015| #no change as its not the minimal value for k1
|  B|  e|04-01-2014|01-01-2020| #no change as its not the minimal value for k1 plus its over the limit
|  C|  a|01-01-2020|01-01-2020| #no change as no matching value found in df2
+---+---+----------+----------+
```

thanks!!!

Comment: Join first and once you have 4 columns use case when to determine the final 2 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will be correct:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = [('A','a','03-05-2010','02-02-2019'),
   ('B','a','02-12-2010','01-02-2011'),
   ('B','b','02-12-2010','01-02-2011'),
   ('B','c','02-12-2010','01-02-2011'),
   ('B','d','03-01-2013','01-03-2015'),
   ('B','e','04-01-2014','01-01-2020'),
   ('C','a','01-01-2020','01-01-2020')
 ]

schema = StructType([ \
   StructField("k1",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("k2",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("start",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("end",StringType(),True), \
 ])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema).alias("df1")
df1.show()

data2 = [('A','a','03-05-2010','02-02-2019'),
   ('B','a','01-01-2008','01-02-2008'),
   ('B','b','01-11-2009','01-12-2009'),
   ('B','c','02-01-2010','01-02-2010'),
   ('B','e','04-01-2014','01-01-2020'),
   ('D','a','01-01-2000','01-01-2001')
 ]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema).alias("df2")
df2.show()
```

Join:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1.join(df2, (df1.k1 == df2.k1) & (df1.k2 == df2.k2), how='left') \
        .select(df1.k1,
                df1.k2,
                F.expr("""Coalesce(CASE WHEN TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(df2.start, 'MM-dd-yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP)) > 
                        TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(df1.start, 'MM-dd-yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP)) THEN df1.start ELSE df2.start END,
                        df1.start) """).alias("start"),
                F.expr("""Coalesce(CASE WHEN TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(df2.end, 'MM-dd-yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP)) > 
                        TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(df1.end, 'MM-dd-yyyy') AS TIMESTAMP)) THEN df1.end ELSE df2.end END, 
                        df1.end)""").alias("end")).sort(df1.k1.asc(),df1.k2.asc() ).show()
```

Result:

```
+---+---+----------+----------+
| k1| k2|     start|       end|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  A|  a|03-05-2010|02-02-2019|
|  B|  a|01-01-2008|01-02-2008|
|  B|  b|01-11-2009|01-12-2009|
|  B|  c|02-01-2010|01-02-2010|
|  B|  d|03-01-2013|01-03-2015|
|  B|  e|04-01-2014|01-01-2020|
|  C|  a|01-01-2020|01-01-2020|
+---+---+----------+----------+
```